# Rails - match route to namespace controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
match '/submit_expense/:id' => 'expenses#submit_expense', :as => 'submit_expense'
```

How would I direct this to my :admin namespace?  Do I have to define the match inside the namespace declaration?

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing

Comment: I've read through that, what I am trying to determine is the proper way to match a custom method with a namespace, I have moved the match statement into my namespace declaration, and it works.  But is that the proper way?

Comment: Oh! well yeah I guess you would have to put your match declaration inside the namespace.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

in `routes.rb` this might work...

```
namespace :admin do
  match '/submit_expense/:id' => 'expenses#submit_expense', :as => 'submit_expense'
end
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this would generate the path: /admin/submit_expense rather than just plain old /submit_expense

Comment: @ChrisO'Sullivan, you're right, it does.  I'm looking for a way to point to a namespaced controller, but not influence the path.

Comment: If you want to refer to a name spaced controller then you can use `module: 'admin'. Find out more here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 27):

You can just use / like when you use the controller generator:

```
match '/submit_expense/:id' => 'admin/expenses#submit_expense', :as => 'submit_expense'
```

Answer (score 3):

You also can just use `to:` directive like this:

```
  get '/submit_expense/:id', to: 'admin/expenses#submit_expense'
```